# How to improve performance when fetching 3rd order connections in neo4j database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j database to track connections between people. I need to track 3rd order connection(something similar to how linkedin does this), but i've faced some issues with performance. In my test database i have approximately 3 thousand users with 3 to 8 connections of the first order(contacts). When fetching second order connections everything seems to be good with the performance. But fetching 3rd order connections takes a long time. I use CYPHER queries to fetch the data. Only profile ids and connections between them are stored in the database.

here is the query itself:

```
THIRD_ORDER_CONNECTIONS = <<-CYPHER
  START n=node:profile(id='%{id}')
  MATCH n-[:contacts]-common_contact_1-[:contacts]-common_contact_2-[:contacts]-profile
  WHERE common_contact.id <> %{exclude_id} AND common_contact_1.id <> common_contact_2.id
  RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT profile.id)
CYPHER
```

It takes 48 seconds on my local machine. So the question is - how can i improve the performance or change the query to get 3rd order connections for appropriate time?

Comment: does it improve any faster if you omit the whole WHERE clause?

Comment: @ulkas
Omitting the `WHERE` clause made neo4j perform the query almost two times slower. ( 39.240216) without `WHERE` clause versus ( 22.606653) with `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not valid: `common_contact.id` does not resolve to an identifier

- How many results do you get back?
- How does the query time change if you add a direction `-->` t your query?
- Please use parameters instead of ruby substitution.
- Try `RETURN profile.id` (distinct needs to keep everything in memory for the unique filtering)
- Normally cypher takes care of uniqueness, so `common_contact_1.id <> common_contact_2.id` might be unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with neo4j version 1.9.M01? There are Cypher performance improvements for straight forward patterns like this which could make a huge difference, where it off-loads more work to the traversal framework.